# How to deploy a node.js app to Azure in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy a node.js Web App from Visual Studio Online to Azure Web App. Visual Studi Online offers the possibility to build the app online and then to deploy it to azure.

I added the build script "Visual Studio Build" and then the "Azure Web App Deployment":

[image: Visual Studio Online Build Process]

The "Visual Studio Build" works fine. In the build process step "Azure Web App Deployment" I added different paths for "Web Deploy Package". Nothing works.

[image: Azure Web App Deployment]

Do you know how to build and deploy the node.js web app to Azure?
Or do you know which path to use for the "Web Deploy Package" in the process step "Azure Web App Deployment"?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Now the VSO allows the file picker to choose the path to the Web Deploy package.

I am not sure whether Visual Studio Build will create a deployment package for a Node.JS application.

You can try one of the two things.

1. You can create your own zip package from the code by using the generic powershell task and then put the zip's full path on the agent machine in Web Deploy Package field.
2. You can always check-in the zipped file which then can be selected using file-picker.